# Swift - Array of dictionary insert into another array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift, dictionary, insert

I declared

```
let ay: [String:String] = ["key1":"verios", "key2":"fdsf"]
var array = ["apple", "banana", "dragonfruit"]
```

when I use

```
array.insert(ay, at:2)
```

or

```
array = ay + array
```

There will have an error:

> error: Functions and Methods.xcplaygroundpage:22:14: error: cannot
>   convert value of type '[String : String]' to expected argument type
>   'String'

I am new in swift. I want to do something like codes below in objective c.

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{
                       @"Key1" : @NO,
                       @"Key2" : @1.0f,
                       @"Key3" : @"String",
                       };

NSMutableArray *ary = @[@"sad", @"and", @"cry"];
NSArray *ay = @[dict, dict, dict];
[ary insertObject:ay atIndex:2];
```

but I can't achieve this in Swift.

Comment: Could you tell us why you want to do this? Changing the array type to `[Any]` will indeed allow you to do this, but it is very unlikely that this is actually what you want to do.

Comment: @overactor Actually I am just studying. What I thought was to manage the respondObject from JSON to some easy access dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is of type `[String]` and when you insert `ay` which is of type `[String:String]` it gives you error ..

So just a change type of array to `[Any]` like

```
 var array:[Any] = ["apple", "banana", "dragonfruit"]
```

---

**Final Code:**

```
let ay: [String:String] = ["key1":"verios", "key2":"fdsf"]
var array:[Any] = ["apple", "banana", "dragonfruit"]

array.insert(ay, at:2)

print(array)  //Result :  ["apple", "banana", ["key1": "verios", "key2": "fdsf"], "dragonfruit"]
```

Comment: Oh! That's it! Thank You!

Comment: Is
let ay: [String:String] = ["key1":"verios", "key2":"fdsf"]
means the same of NSDictionary in Objective C?

Answer (score 0):

You must use Any...

```
 let ay: [String:String] = ["key1":"verios", "key2":"fdsf"]
    var array : [Any] = ["apple", "banana", "dragonfruit"]

    array.append(ay)
```